# How to add google analytics in electron

Tags: google-analytics, electron, electron-builder

I want to add google analytics in electron application. As it is JS, I see there is only one option create an account for 'website'. Does anyone has used google analytics in electron app for windows and mac? which account to create and what is the further process?

Comment: Do you tried add GA link in index.html ?

Comment: You could as well use `electron-google-analytics` - check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-google-analytics (https://github.com/vacu/electron-google-analytics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [universal-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics#setting-persistent-parameters) and in the server, I set my tracking Id and set `global.param = ua`. Now in renderer I used this param to access all features.

Comment: Could you explain how this resolves the question? The question indicates that you weren't able to register the app. How did you register and then use universal-analytics